# Salt size in /etc/shadow

Tags: centos, rhel, password, hashsum

After user password change the size of salt decreased in RHEL/Centos 6, eg:

```
cat /etc/shadow

...
root:$6$FkMNsNxT$FW77....................nbL0......
bin:*:15422:0:99999:7:::
...
```

As you can see, FkMNsNxT is 8 characters.

Why it happens? In the beginning, after installation, the size is 16 chars.

Comment: Did you change password encryption algorithm? A 16 character salt means 128 bits, which indicates another algorithm than `sha512crypt` which is what the current password is encoded with (see `man 5 crypt`).

Comment: No, password encryption not changed

Comment: If you say that the salt was 128 bits previously, then the encryption method has _obviously_ changed.

Comment: @Kusalananda, no, that doesn't follow. both the sha256crypt and sha512crypt algorithms can take variable-length salts. This is quite a valid hash of the password `foobar`: `$6$abc$cyugVWWBuhMmAXlbiQBF7DHoFwA0ff6g9AF6j6N1EKMUXHyGGvjkzhQdzV13AFJpV7xnnx8eC.f372Ypp1Zug.`

Comment: @ilkkachu I might obviously be interpreting the `crypt(5)` manual wrong when it says that `sha512crypt` uses a variable salt of between 6 and 96 bits (less than 128 bits).  The entry that you show seems to be using a 24 bit salt (the `abc` value).

Comment: @Kusalananda, ah, hmm. 16 chars of base64 encoded data would be 16*6 = 96 bits, which might explain it. They can't be arbitrary bytes anyway, since `$`, `:` and newline are used as separators in `/etc/shadow` and other control chars might also cause issues. I tested that with Perl, and it cuts the salt at 16 chars (but didn't enforce the base64 alphabet, allowing hashes like `$6$!!!$`, but they didn't work with the actual PAM module)

Comment: @ilkkachu The salt is base64-encoded? Ah, yes it is, in a way. Well then.  Then it's just a matter of the OP getting another salt value. I don't really see an issue here any longer.

Comment: yep, base64 but with a custom alphabet (`./0-9A-Za-z` vs. the more standard `A-Za-z0-9+/`, so the order is different too, not just the two special chars)

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the program that creates the password hash to determine the salt, and its length. Based on [what I've looked up before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/301334/170373), there's at least two different pieces of code for that going around. E.g. on Debian/Ubuntu, changing the password via PAM (with `passwd`), creates a 16 character salt always, but using `chpasswd -a SHA512` creates a variable-length salt. On RHEL/CentOS plain `passwd` used the latter algorithm when I last tested.

The installer probably just uses different code than whatever the user used to change their password.